# Perl to Bash: How does the newline character-escape "\n" behave special?

Tags: perl, bash, shell, escaping, newline

When I run this without using the extra-escape for the `"\n"`, `hexdump` doesn't print the `0a` for the embedded newline.
Why does the `"\n"` need here an extra-treatment?
(While searching for an answer I found [String::ShellQuote](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String%3a%3aShellQuote) which does the escaping.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use utf8;
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';
use charnames qw(:full);
use IPC::System::Simple qw(system);

for my $i ( 0x08 .. 0x0d ) {
    printf "0x%02x - %s\n", $i, '\N{' . charnames::viacode( $i ) . '}';
    my $string = "It" . chr( $i ) . "s"; 
    $string =~ s/\n/\\n/g;
    system( "echo -e \Q$string\E | hexdump -C" );
    say "";
}
```

Comment: Quotemeta does escape strings inside perl. The `echo` command takes the correctly printed `\n` and interprets it correctly as newline in bash. You feed `stdout` linewise to hexdump which does not get the newline char unless it is shell-escaped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you don't convert the newline to the two characters `\n`, you're executing the command

```
echo -e \
| hexdump -C
```

To `sh`, that's equivalent to

```
echo -e | hexdump -C
```

---

When you convert the newline to the two characters `\n`, you're executing the command

```
echo -e \\n | hexdump -C
```

That passes the two characters `\n` to `echo`, for which it outputs a newline under `-e`.

---

You don't need to use `-e` and to create escapes for `-e`. You could create a proper shell command. That command would be:

```
echo '
' | hexdump -C
```

You can do that a number of ways. You could roll out your own solution.

```
(my $sh_literal = $string) =~ s/'/'\\''/g;
$sh_literal = "'$sh_literal'";
system( "echo $sh_literal | hexdump -C" );
```

There is [String::ShellQuote](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String%3a%3aShellQuote).

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );
my $sh_literal = shell_quote($string);
system( "echo $sh_literal | hexdump -C" );
```

Finally, you could avoid the shell entirely.

```
open(my $fh, "|-", "hexdump", "-vC")
   or die("Could not start hexdump: $!\n");
print($fh $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

as @mugenkenichi commented echo is interpreting your strings too, so you have to escape special characters twice, once for perl and once for echo.

Instead this approach might be more convenient:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use utf8;
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';
use charnames qw(:full);
use IPC::System::Simple qw(system);

for my $i ( 0x08 .. 0x0d ) {
    printf "0x%02x - %s\n", $i, '\N{' . charnames::viacode($i) . '}';
    my $string = "It" . chr($i) . "s";
    open( my $fh, "| hexdump -vC" )
      or die "could not talk to hexdump";
    print $fh $string;
    say "";
}
```